# Jungledisk does not restore my files. How can this be fixed?

Tags: backup, cloud-storage, amazon-s3, jungledisk

I backup my files with Jungledisk for many years now, my backup is on Amazon S3 and is ~600 GB in size. Unluckily there came the time when I need to restore some files (my email files got damaged).

When I do restore in Jungledisk, I get these errors (all same):

[image: Jungledisk restore errors]

If I go to details of one of them, I get this:

```
Error Details (Jungle Disk Workgroup 3.22.1.0xHTTPBadResult -  (404) Error Code: NoSuchKey
NoSuchKey: The specified key does not exist.
Exception Code: xHTTPBadResult (9)
Time: 13.02.2018 19:27:12 (GMT+1)
Detailed Message:  (404) Error Code: NoSuchKey
Server Error Code: NoSuchKey
Detailed Server Message: The specified key does not exist.
HTTP Result Code: 404
HTTP Headers:
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
x-amz-request-id: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
x-amz-id-2: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Content-Type: application/xml
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 13 Feb 2018 18:27:11 GMT
Server: AmazonS3

HTTP Body:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>NoSuchKey</Code><Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message><Key>rach1-s3/BACKUPS/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX/CHUNKS/0000729696</Key><RequestId>XXXXXXXXX</RequestId><HostId>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</HostId></Error>
Error Location: S3Request.cpp:170 S3Request::ReadFile
   via JungleDiskBulk.cpp:141 JungleDiskBulk::NetworkReadObject
   via ChunkManager.cpp:533 ChunkManager::EnsureDownloadedChunk
   via BlockBackupManager.cpp:2401 BlockBackupManager::RestoreOneFile
   via BlockBackupManager.cpp:2412 BlockBackupManager::RestoreOneFile
```

(I have replaced some cryptic stuff with XXXX to not share any S3 account information)

I have contacted `support@jungledisk.com` but it's alsmost a week and no answer.

How can I restore my files? Is this possible?

Or was I paying a lot of money all these years for JD and storage and never had any backup actually?

Comment: `NoSuchKey` means "file not found" in the bucket.  Inspect the bucket contents using the S3 console.  Be sure you don't have a bucket lifecycle policy that's purging (expiring) old objects from the bucket.

Comment: (Note also that `x-amz-request-id` and `x-amz-id-2` don't convey any sensitive information.  They're essentially just log markers that AWS support can use to trace requests through the system, in cases where that's necessary.)

Comment: Thanks for `x-amz` clarification. As for the chunk which it cannot find, I'm trying to check this with Cloudberry Explorer, but this will take some hours probably, as all chunks are in one folder and it takes time to enumerate it. As for bucket policy - I think it should be some valid setting, because the bucket was created by JungleDisk. But how can I check it? I have tried `CB Explorer -> right click on bucket -> Bucket Policy` and `Bucket Lifecycle`. Both show empty dialogs.

Comment: I have verified with - the file with that name (`rach1-s3/BACKUPS/5bb05ba5dfedc5da42de3f7a554e481f/CHUNKS/0000729696`) does not exist in my backup.

Comment: Send another email to Jungledisk support today. This is a week and one day after initial email, three emails sent so far, and no answer at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to answer my own question - so at the end I wasn't able to restore the files. Jungledisk fails with these errors no matter what I try. It seems there are some files missing in the S3 bucket. Probably this is a result of some software error in Jungledisk, as this was the only software which created and maintained this bucket. The files are stored split to chunks so there's no way to get to this data with some external software.

I have sent several emails to Jungledisk support, but this didn't help either. It has been over two weeks and there is no single answer to them. Everything I got was confirmation that my credit card was charged for another month. That's really sad.